# SQL GROUP BY return empty set

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, grouping

I have a table rental:

```
rentalId    int(11)              
Customer_customerId     int(11)          
Vehicle_registrationNumber  varchar(20)              
startDate   datetime             
endDate     datetime         
pickUpLocation  int(11)                  
returnLocation  int(11)                      
booking_time    timestamp                
timePickedUp    timestamp            
timeReturned    timestamp
```

and table payment:

```
paymentId   int(11)                      
Rental_rentalId     int(11)      
amountDue   decimal(10,2)                
amountPaid  decimal(10,2)            
paymentDate     timestamp
```

I run two group by functions, first one counts the number of reservations and sums the payments by day, this function only works as expected when having pickUpLocation` is omitted, otherwise it returns incorrect values.  :

```
SELECT COUNT(rentalId) AS number_of_rentals, MONTH(booking_time) AS month,
`YEAR(booking_time) AS year, 
CONCAT(DAY(booking_time), '-', MONTH(booking_time), '-',`
YEAR(booking_time) ) AS date, SUM(amountDue) AS total_value, SUM(amountPaid) AS 
total_paid, `pickUpLocation`

FROM (`rental`)
JOIN `payment` ON `payment`.`Rental_rentalId` = `rental`.`rentalId`

GROUP BY DAY(booking_time)

HAVING `month` = 2
AND `year` = 2012
AND `pickUpLocation` = 1
ORDER BY `booking_time` desc

LIMIT 31
```

The second function is expected to sum the reservations and payments (both due and received) for the entire month, for a specific location:

```
 SELECT COUNT(rentalId) AS number_of_rentals, MONTH(booking_time) AS month, 
 YEAR(booking_time) AS year, SUM(amountDue) AS total_value, 
 SUM(amountPaid) AS total_paid,
 `pickUpLocation`

  FROM (`rental`)
  JOIN `payment` ON `payment`.`Rental_rentalId` = `rental`.`rentalId`

  GROUP BY MONTH(booking_time)

  HAVING `month` = 2
  AND `year` = 2012
  AND `pickUpLocation` = 1
  ORDER BY `booking_time` desc
```

It works for some locations and doesn't work for others (returns correct set when there are many reservations, but when there are only few, it returns empty set). I use MySQL. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to push some conditions from `HAVING` to `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE YEAR(booking_time) = 2012
  AND MONTH(booking_time) = 2
  AND `pickUpLocation` = 1

GROUP BY DAY(booking_time)

LIMIT 31
```

For a specific month, you don't even need the `GROUP BY`:

```
WHERE YEAR(booking_time) = 2012
  AND MONTH(booking_time) = 2
  AND `pickUpLocation` = 1
```

---

The above condition is not very good regarding performance:

```
WHERE YEAR(booking_time) = 2012
  AND MONTH(booking_time) = 2
```

You should change it into:

```
WHERE booking_time >= '2012-02-01'
  AND booking_time < '2012-03-01'
```

so the query can use an index on `booking_time` (if you have or you add one in the future) and so it doesn't call the `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` functions for every row of the table.

Comment: That's solved it, thanks very much for the code and for your advice regarding performance!

Answer (score 3):

You're doing an inner join between `rental` and `payment` which means you will only ever get rentals that have been paid for. If you want to find rentals without payment info too in your result, you need to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of just an (inner) `JOIN`.

Note that that may result in NULLs in your result if there are no payments to account for, so you may have to adjust the output of your query using one of the [control flow functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html).

Edit: You're also `GROUP`ing before your conditions, that will `GROUP` all rows for a month into one single row. Since the year and the PickupLocation may vary, you will get random values (of the ones available) in those two fields. `HAVING` will then filter on those random fields, leaving you with a possibly empty result set. `WHERE` on the other hand will see every row before `GROUP`ing and do the right thing (tm) on a row to row basis, so the conditions should be put there instead.

(The same change should probably be done to your first, working, query)

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99294/16).

Comment: I changed this JOIN to LEFT JOIN, but it's still the same. There are no NULLs in amountDue and amountPaid fields, the default for those is 0.00, but it still returns empty set. For example, the first function returns this: 
(Date) 16-2-2012  (Reservations)1  (Amount due)31.00 (Amount paid) 10.00 GBP, while the second, with the same parameters (year, month, branch) returns empty set.

Comment: @tomsky I get responses with your query for the same data you're listing; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f78c/4

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason it doesn't work with my data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99294/1